# 2D Graphics issue - Probably Logic

Tags: java, swing, awt

Trying to make a health bar above my player (Using 2d graphics), but I'm having issues.

I've made sure I'm giving an int and not a double.

f is my JFrame.
f.board is a a JLabel array (17x17) that is my board for the game
p getHealth returns 100
p getHealthTotal returns 200
The 50s you see represent how big the health bar should be

```
    void paint() {
    f.glass = new JPanel() {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(img, f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getX() - 28, f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getY() - 20,
                    null);



            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawRoundRect(f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getX() + 5, f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getY() - 35,
                    50, 10, 5, 5);

            g2d.setColor(healthColor);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getX() + 5,f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getY() - 35,
                    (p.getHealth() / p.getHealthTotal()) * 50, 10,5,5);
            g2d.setColor(damageColor);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getX() + 5 + (p.getHealth() / p.getHealthTotal()) * 50,
                    f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getY() - 35, 50 - ( p.getHealth() / p.getHealthTotal()) * 50,
                    10, 5, 5);


            /*g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawRoundRect(f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getX() + 10, f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getY() - 25, 40, 5, 5, 5);
            g2d.setColor(expColor);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getX() + 10, f.board[p.getY()][p.getX()].getY() - 25, p.getExp() / 100 * 40, 5, 5, 5);
            /*g2d.setColor(expBorder);
            g2d.drawRoundRect(740, 10, 100, 40, 5, 5);
            g2d.setColor(expColor);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(740, 10, p.getExp(), 40, 5, 5);

            g2d.setColor(healthBorder);
            g2d.drawRoundRect(610, 10, 100, 40, 5, 5);
            g2d.setColor(healthColor);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(610, 10, p.getHealth() / p.getHealthTotal() * 100, 40, 5, 5);

            p.ge*/

            g2d.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/BossBattles/Images/Settings.png"), 925, 15, null);
        }
    };
    f.glass.setOpaque(false);
    f.setGlassPane(f.glass);
    f.glass.setVisible(true);
    f.glass.repaint();
}
```

I'm expecting a bar, half green, half red. However, I'm getting a filled red bar.

I've tried a few different values for p.getHealth, but all (That I've tried) return a completely red bar. (Except 200 which returns a green bar)

Comment: 1. Don't override `paint`, override `paintComponent` instead; 2. Call the paint methods super implement before performing any custom painting. 3. Don't load resources in the paint method, painting is for painting only. 4. Don't reference `src` directly from within your code, it won't exist once the app is packaged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't override `paint`, override `paintComponent` instead
2. Call the paint methods super implement before performing any custom painting.
3. Don't load resources in the paint method, painting is for painting
   only.
4. Don't reference `src` directly from within your code, it
   won't exist once the app is packaged

I "suspect" that `p.getHealth()` and `p.getHealthTotal()` are `int`s, which means that the result is been truncated to a `int` as well, dropping the part you're interested in.

One solution is to make them `double` or cast `p.getHealthTotal()` to `double` when you make the calculation.

Now, having said that, I'd also make some minor modifications to the order of your painting.

Painting should be done in reverse order (background to foreground) and I would simply paint the background red color to occupy the full range, as it's kind of pointless to do much else...

```
g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
g2d.fillRoundRect(
        5,
        5, 90,
        10, 5, 5);

g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g2d.fillRoundRect(
        5, 5,
        (int)((health / totalHealth) * 90), 10, 5, 5);

g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2d.drawRoundRect(
        5, 5,
        90, 10, 5, 5);
```

which outputs...

[image: Example]

Comment: Changing health and health to a double then typecasting worked, thanks.